# Maven system scope for testing purposes

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle

I wrote a little framework for testing microservices. Now I packed my contracts into a jar which will be used to test my framework, but i don't want to deploy them to our nexus. so my pom contains

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mycompany.testframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.dummy-contract</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/contract-dummy.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

now if i want to use the framework in another project (using gradle) I get this error message:

```
Processing of C:\Users\dam\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\mycompany.testframework\TestFramework\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\5859a002118d47b4237425d25dfc79ea1d7eb829\TestFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom failed:
'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for mycompany:test.dummy-contract:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/contract-dummy.jar in mycompany.testframework:TestFramework:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I need the dependency for my jenkins test and build but not for "delivery". any suggestions?

Comment: It works here, did you have other pom or user settings that override defaults?

Comment: my problem is, that i don't want to have the dummy-contract on the other project as dependency.

Comment: the problem is the maven exception, but your fragment is correct, so the cause could be a wrong maven configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by adding the dependency to a profile wich only will be used for the test-framework and on the jenkins

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test-dummy</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/contract-dummy.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.company.testframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>test.dummy-contract</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/contract-dummy.jar</systemPath>

                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```